# EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when using the variable in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, background, exc-bad-access

I have react native application with background task.
I want to detect if the app started in the background, prevent the react native bridge initialization, and postpone it until the app become active
To achieve this, I have declared a boolean variable and when I initialize the bridge, I set this variable to true. So in `applicationDidBecomeActive` method I can check this variable and find out if the bridge has already been initialized or needs to be initialized
This is my code:

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isInitialized;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  // if app is running in the background, then do not init react native bridge
  if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    return YES;
  }
  
  self.isInitialized = YES;
  // initialize react native bridge here

  return YES;
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  if( !self.isInitialized ) {
    self.isInitialized = YES;
    // initialize react native bridge here
  }
}
```

The problem is that in some cases, the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in the backgroun. Which I guess is related to this line `if( !self.isInitialized ) {`

Crash trace:

```
OS Version: iOS 15.3.1 (19D52)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: BUS_NOOP at 0x0000007dd5032378
Crashed Thread: 4

Application Specific Information:
instance > onDidBecomeActive: > serverDisableLogs > setManager: > XTUM >
Attempted to dereference garbage pointer 0x7dd5032378.

Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x332ade2ec         lookUpImpOrForward
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x332ad99e0         [inlined] _objc_msgSend_uncached
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x332ad99e0         _objc_msgSend_uncached
3   RaxelPulse                      0x10601f2a0         aes_init
4   RaxelPulse                      0x106034528         unzeof
5   RaxelPulse                      0x106039478         unzeof
6   CoreFoundation                  0x30195af84         __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3019f6c38         ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3019c9ff0         _CFXRegistrationPost
9   CoreFoundation                  0x301970df0         _CFXNotificationPost
10  Foundation                      0x304994f54         -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
11  Foundation                      0x304a0d32c         NSProcessInfoNotifyPowerState
12  libsystem_notify.dylib          0x340f6f6bc         notify_cancel
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x301351450         _dispatch_block_async_invoke2
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x30134266c         _dispatch_client_callout
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x301353efc         _dispatch_root_queue_drain
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x301354604         _dispatch_worker_thread2
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f850b4         _pthread_wqthread

Thread 0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515504         mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515b98         mach_msg
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x30135d288         _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x30135d638         dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x3e2fc8b98         xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync
5   Foundation                      0x3049b9130         __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_WAITING_FOR_A_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLY__
6   Foundation                      0x3049bf0b0         -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]
7   Foundation                      0x3049d24c0         -[NSXPCConnection _sendSelector:withProxy:arg1:]
8   Foundation                      0x3049a4488         _NSXPCDistantObjectSimpleMessageSend1
9   CoreLocation                    0x3100bc038         CLGetStatusBarIconState
10  CoreLocation                    0x3100ba34c         CLClientIsLocationServicesEnabled
11  CoreLocation                    0x3100ba010         CLClientRetrieveAuthorizationStatus
12  RaxelPulse                      0x10601f25c         aes_init
13  RaxelPulse                      0x106034528         unzeof
14  Foundation                      0x3049ac76c         __NSFireTimer
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3019de314         __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
16  CoreFoundation                  0x301962cec         __CFRunLoopDoTimer
17  CoreFoundation                  0x30195d4e8         __CFRunLoopDoTimers
18  CoreFoundation                  0x30193bd04         __CFRunLoopRun
19  CoreFoundation                  0x30194f464         CFRunLoopRunSpecific
20  GraphicsServices                0x3390b5388         GSEventRunModal
21  UIKitCore                       0x30679b5cc         -[UIApplication _run]
22  UIKitCore                       0x306519f70         UIApplicationMain
23  Driverly                        0x204b8b580         main (main.m:7)
24  <unknown>                       0x105cadaa4         <redacted>

Thread 1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515b2c         __workq_kernreturn
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f8513c         _pthread_wqthread

Thread 2 name: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515504         mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515b98         mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x301937734         __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30193ba28         __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30194f464         CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   Foundation                      0x304992c80         -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
6   Foundation                      0x3049d3db4         -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]
7   UIKitCore                       0x306714748         -[UIEventFetcher threadMain]
8   Foundation                      0x3049e23f8         __NSThread__start__
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 3
0   libapple_nghttp2.dylib          0x3e096497c         nghttp2_rcbuf_decref
1   libapple_nghttp2.dylib          0x3e09675d0         [inlined] hd_context_free
2   libapple_nghttp2.dylib          0x3e09675d0         hd_context_free
3   libapple_nghttp2.dylib          0x3e0963260         nghttp2_session_del
4   CFNetwork                       0x302a4a4a0         _CFURLCachePersistMemoryToDiskNow
5   CFNetwork                       0x302a4d068         _CFURLCachePersistMemoryToDiskNow
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x301340920         _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x30134266c         _dispatch_client_callout
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x301349df0         _dispatch_lane_serial_drain
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x30134a998         _dispatch_lane_invoke
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x30134bc80         _dispatch_workloop_invoke
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3013551b4         _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f850f0         _pthread_wqthread

Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x332ade2ec         lookUpImpOrForward
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x332ad99e0         [inlined] _objc_msgSend_uncached
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x332ad99e0         _objc_msgSend_uncached
3   RaxelPulse                      0x10601f2a0         aes_init
4   RaxelPulse                      0x106034528         unzeof
5   RaxelPulse                      0x106039478         unzeof
6   CoreFoundation                  0x30195af84         __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3019f6c38         ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3019c9ff0         _CFXRegistrationPost
9   CoreFoundation                  0x301970df0         _CFXNotificationPost
10  Foundation                      0x304994f54         -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
11  Foundation                      0x304a0d32c         NSProcessInfoNotifyPowerState
12  libsystem_notify.dylib          0x340f6f6bc         notify_cancel
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x301351450         _dispatch_block_async_invoke2
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x30134266c         _dispatch_client_callout
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x301353efc         _dispatch_root_queue_drain
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x301354604         _dispatch_worker_thread2
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f850b4         _pthread_wqthread

Thread 5 name: com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515504         mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515b98         mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x301937734         __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30193ba28         __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30194f464         CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3019cfb24         CFRunLoopRun
6   CoreMotion                      0x31bac2bc0         CLMotionActivity::isTypeInVehicle
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 6 name: com.facebook.react.JavaScript
0   Driverly                        0x204d6ed4c         __copy_helper_block_ea8_32r
1   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x3e2e7d6b8         _Block_copy
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3013408e4         _dispatch_Block_copy
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x30134704c         dispatch_async
4   Driverly                        0x204ca5208         reanimated::REAIOSScheduler::scheduleOnUI (REAIOSScheduler.mm:31)
5   Driverly                        0x204c90e88         reanimated::StoreUser::~StoreUser (JSIStoreValueUser.cpp:41)
6   Driverly                        0x204cb8544         [inlined] reanimated::ShareableValue::~ShareableValue (ShareableValue.h:19)
7   Driverly                        0x204cb8544         [inlined] reanimated::ShareableValue::~ShareableValue (ShareableValue.h:19)
8   Driverly                        0x204cb8544         reanimated::ShareableValue::~ShareableValue (ShareableValue.h:19)
9   Driverly                        0x204bd62d0         [inlined] std::__1::__shared_count::__release_shared (memory:2506)
10  Driverly                        0x204bd62d0         [inlined] std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared (memory:2548)
11  Driverly                        0x204bd62d0         std::__1::shared_ptr<T>::~shared_ptr (memory:3238)
12  Driverly                        0x204c902c4         [inlined] std::__1::shared_ptr<T>::~shared_ptr (memory:3236)
13  Driverly                        0x204c902c4         [inlined] std::__1::pair<T>::~pair (utility:297)
14  Driverly                        0x204c902c4         [inlined] std::__1::pair<T>::~pair (utility:297)
15  Driverly                        0x204c902c4         std::__1::allocator_traits<T>::destroy<T> (allocator_traits.h:317)
16  Driverly                        0x204c90290         std::__1::__hash_table<T>::__deallocate_node (__hash_table:1580)
17  Driverly                        0x204c90250         std::__1::__hash_table<T>::~__hash_table (__hash_table:1519)
18  Driverly                        0x204c901f0         [inlined] std::__1::__hash_table<T>::~__hash_table (__hash_table:1511)
19  Driverly                        0x204c901f0         [inlined] std::__1::unordered_map<T>::~unordered_map (unordered_map:1044)
20  Driverly                        0x204c901f0         [inlined] std::__1::unordered_map<T>::~unordered_map (unordered_map:1042)
21  Driverly                        0x204c901f0         [inlined] reanimated::FrozenObject::~FrozenObject (FrozenObject.h:12)
22  Driverly                        0x204c901f0         reanimated::FrozenObject::~FrozenObject (FrozenObject.h:12)
23  Driverly                        0x204bd62d0         [inlined] std::__1::__shared_count::__release_shared (memory:2506)
24  Driverly                        0x204bd62d0         [inlined] std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared (memory:2548)
25  Driverly                        0x204bd62d0         std::__1::shared_ptr<T>::~shared_ptr (memory:3238)
26  Driverly                        0x204dcd5cc         [inlined] std::__1::shared_ptr<T>::~shared_ptr (memory:3236)
27  Driverly                        0x204dcd5cc         [inlined] facebook::jsc::detail::HostObjectProxyBase::~HostObjectProxyBase (JSCRuntime.cpp:695)
28  Driverly                        0x204dcd5cc         [inlined] facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject::HostObjectProxy::~HostObjectProxy (JSCRuntime.cpp:712)
29  Driverly                        0x204dcd5cc         [inlined] facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject::HostObjectProxy::~HostObjectProxy (JSCRuntime.cpp:712)
30  Driverly                        0x204dcd5cc         facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject::HostObjectProxy::finalize (JSCRuntime.cpp:817)
31  JavaScriptCore                  0x317cc7638         JSC::JSCallbackObject<T>::destroy
32  JavaScriptCore                  0x31825da10         JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::specializedSweep<T>
33  JavaScriptCore                  0x31825c184         JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::finishSweepKnowingHeapCellType<T>::lambda::operator()
34  JavaScriptCore                  0x318258ffc         JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::finishSweepKnowingHeapCellType<T>
35  JavaScriptCore                  0x31826010c         JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::sweep
36  JavaScriptCore                  0x3182327b4         JSC::BlockDirectory::sweep
37  JavaScriptCore                  0x3182623bc         JSC::MarkedSpace::sweepBlocks
38  JavaScriptCore                  0x31823bd60         JSC::Heap::sweepSynchronously
39  JavaScriptCore                  0x318240d68         JSC::Heap::finalize
40  JavaScriptCore                  0x318240630         JSC::Heap::handleNeedFinalize
41  JavaScriptCore                  0x3182407c8         JSC::Heap::acquireAccessSlow
42  JavaScriptCore                  0x3186e5588         JSC::JSLock::didAcquireLock
43  JavaScriptCore                  0x31871ba30         JSC::JSRunLoopTimer::timerDidFire
44  JavaScriptCore                  0x31871b75c         JSC::JSRunLoopTimer::Manager::timerDidFire
45  JavaScriptCore                  0x318ad8aa8         WTF::RunLoop::TimerBase::start::lambda::__invoke
46  CoreFoundation                  0x3019de314         __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
47  CoreFoundation                  0x301962cec         __CFRunLoopDoTimer
48  CoreFoundation                  0x30195d4e8         __CFRunLoopDoTimers
49  CoreFoundation                  0x30193bd04         __CFRunLoopRun
50  CoreFoundation                  0x30194f464         CFRunLoopRunSpecific
51  Driverly                        0x204d0a640         +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] (RCTCxxBridge.mm:367)
52  Foundation                      0x3049e23f8         __NSThread__start__
53  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 7 name: JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515f90         __psynch_cvwait
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f8c250         _pthread_cond_wait
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x332c2de74         std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x318b4daac         bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x318b4d4e0         bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x318b4e99c         std::__1::__thread_proxy<T>
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 8 name: AVAudioSession Notify Thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515504         mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515b98         mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x301937734         __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30193ba28         __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30194f464         CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   AudioSession                    0x31419e304         CADeprecated::GenericRunLoopThread::Entry
6   AudioSession                    0x3141a7d60         CADeprecated::CAPThread::Entry
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 9
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515ae4         __semwait_signal
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3177beefc         nanosleep
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3177d2f38         sleep
3   Driverly                        0x204e02824         monitorCachedData (SentryCrashCachedData.c:139)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 10 name: SentryCrash Exception Handler (Secondary)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515504         mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515b98         mach_msg
2   Driverly                        0x204e0f6ec         handleExceptions (SentryCrashMonitor_MachException.c:266)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 12 name: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515504         mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515b98         mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x301937734         __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30193ba28         __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30194f464         CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CFNetwork                       0x302be050c         _CFURLStorageSessionCopyIdentifier
6   Foundation                      0x3049e23f8         __NSThread__start__
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 13
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f84e8c         start_wqthread

Thread 14
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f84e8c         start_wqthread

Thread 15
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515504         mach_msg_trap
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515b98         mach_msg
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x30135d288         _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x30135d638         dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x3e2fc8b98         xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync
5   Foundation                      0x3049b9130         __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_WAITING_FOR_A_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLY__
6   Foundation                      0x3049bf0b0         -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]
7   CoreFoundation                  0x30195e2a0         ___forwarding___
8   CoreFoundation                  0x30195d65c         __forwarding_prep_0___
9   CFNetwork                       0x3029b8c0c         _CFNetworkSetATSContext
10  CFNetwork                       0x3029babdc         CFHTTPMessageCopyRequestURL
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x301340920         _dispatch_call_block_and_release
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x30134266c         _dispatch_client_callout
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x301349df0         _dispatch_lane_serial_drain
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x30134a998         _dispatch_lane_invoke
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x3013551b4         _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f850f0         _pthread_wqthread

Thread 16
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f84e8c         start_wqthread

Thread 17
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515f90         __psynch_cvwait
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f8c250         _pthread_cond_wait
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x318ad02b0         WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x31898bc38         WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<T>
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x318a9acdc         WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<T>::call
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af6198         WTF::Thread::entryPoint
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af8af4         WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 18
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515f90         __psynch_cvwait
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f8c250         _pthread_cond_wait
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x318ad02b0         WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x31898bc38         WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<T>
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x318a9acdc         WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<T>::call
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af6198         WTF::Thread::entryPoint
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af8af4         WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 19
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515f90         __psynch_cvwait
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f8c250         _pthread_cond_wait
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x318ad02b0         WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x31898bc38         WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<T>
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x318a9acdc         WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<T>::call
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af6198         WTF::Thread::entryPoint
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af8af4         WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 20
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515f90         __psynch_cvwait
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f8c250         _pthread_cond_wait
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x318ad02b0         WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x31898bc38         WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<T>
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x318a9acdc         WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<T>::call
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af6198         WTF::Thread::entryPoint
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af8af4         WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 21
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515f90         __psynch_cvwait
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f8c250         _pthread_cond_wait
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x318ad02b0         WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x31898bc38         WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<T>
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x318a9acdc         WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<T>::call
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af6198         WTF::Thread::entryPoint
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af8af4         WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 22
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x370515f90         __psynch_cvwait
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f8c250         _pthread_cond_wait
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x318ad02b0         WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x31898bc38         WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<T>
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x318a9acdc         WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<T>::call
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af6198         WTF::Thread::entryPoint
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x318af8af4         WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f859a0         _pthread_start

Thread 23
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f84e8c         start_wqthread

Thread 24
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3e2f84e8c         start_wqthread
```

Is there a way to prevent this crash?

Comment: There is nothing there that would be crashy. IN fact, all of that will run on the main thread.

Post a crash trace, if you can.

Comment: @bbum I added crash trace. Can you please check again?

Comment: `dereference garbage pointer 0x7dd5032378` something wrong with memory management. Turn on `zombie objects` sanitizer in the scheme diagnostic settings.